# My code always displays a smiley face next to my name

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I made a very simple program which displays the value of the string name and it display my name and a smiley face next to it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[5] = "Rafik";

    printf("%s", name);
}
```

it shows the following error

```
Rafik☺
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect size of the `name` array. it should be `char name[6]` because the C-string literal (in your case `"Rafik"`) always add on an extra character at the end which is the NULL character/terminator `'\0'`.

That's how for example `scanf` knows where is the end of the string.

Comment: out of curiousity, is there a compiler flag that will catch this?  I just ran Rafik's code with -Wall and Wextra with size 5 vs size 6 and didnt get any compile time warnings.

Comment: @KevinCrum there is not such warning because the code is legal, there is nothing wrong with an array of 5 characters, switch to `char name[4]` and with `-Wall` flag on you get _warning: initializer-string for array of ‘char’ is too long_

Comment: @KevinCrum The compiler doesn't know your intentions, maybe you will call it with `printf("%.5s", ...)` as an un-terminated string? This was the use case in hardware limited OS, and why `strncat` fills the buffer with zeros.

Comment: @Alaa Mahran _always add on an extra character at the end ..._ **if it fits**, in this case is not possible.  Good to say that is better to let the compiler do his work and use `char name[] = "Rafik";`